# Socket io multiple connections in react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, sockets, socket.io

I decided to learn socket io and do a little project with it, so I was following the docs creating  an instance and connecting to it.
so on my server side  I have:

```js
onst express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});

app.get("/home", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello");
});

io.on("connect", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on('disconnect',()=>{console.log("socket disconnected")
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("listening");
});
```

and on my client side :

```js
mport React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
 
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:5000";

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  useEffect(()=>{
  const socket = io(ENDPOINT);
  return()=>{socket.emit('disconnect');
     socket.off();}},[endpoint]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="type a message"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However the connection is happening multiple times and many reconnects are happening in the same browser tab, I tried useEffect and it still didn't work once.

In the borwser when I open the dev tools to see the network i see continuously  socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling.
On my console I get the id of the socket then it disconnection message (I updated the code to show it)
here is my index.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You were right to use useEffect for this, but you also need to add the socket connection to the state. You should also pass a callback into your `connect` listener. Try this:

```js
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(ENDPOINT);
    newSocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
      console.log('socket connected', socket);
    })
    
    setSocket(newSocket);
    return () => newSocket.close();
  }, [setSocket]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="type a message"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Note adding the `return () => newSocket.close();` in useEffect cleans up the connection by closing it (and sending the close event) when the user navigates away.

If this doesn't work you can always move the socket connection (and listeners) to outside of the component, like this:

```js
import {io} from "socket.io-client";

const newSocket = io(ENDPOINT);

newSocket.on('connect', (socket) => {
   console.log('socket connected', socket);
})


function App() {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="type a message"
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This might work better, in which case I would move this into its own file and handle all the event listeners in one place.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still gives the same result

Comment: try and update your import statement to look like this `import { io } from "socket.io-client";`

Comment: @Rihabsabri I have edited my answer to show an alternate method of connecting

Comment: Still same issue, I don't know what is causing the multiple reconnects, I thought something was causing the component to re render but i can't seem to solve the real issues i followed some tutorial and tried the documentation code but it's giving me the same result while working for others.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: is it console logging anything? can you update your question with that info?

Comment: just once? are there any connect events happening in your dev console on browser?

Comment: yess there are multiple it will connect and 3 times in a row disconnect and connect again without me changing the browser or updating it

Comment: I think something may be rendering the `App` component multiple times, can you show where the root (`<div id="root"></div>`) of your react DOM is?

Comment: I have edited the code and added more details

Comment: is that the useEffect you tried and it didnt work? (the one in your updated version) because that wont work at all, have you tried the one ive listed?

Comment: yes i have, that's the latest one I tried, also  I m just using the react js boilerplate,  I didn't change anything inside index.html

Comment: and you have tried the second option I mentioned of moving everything above the `App` method? If so I probably cant be of any more help